# Unable to inject module in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use `HandsonTable module` from here https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable

I have loaded the scripts and injected the dependencies:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bower_components/handsontable/dist/pikaday/pikaday.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Angular module:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'angular-jwt', 'ngStorage', 'angular-storage', 'angularCSS', 'ngHandsontable', 'ngMoment', 'pikaday']);
```

I get error saying: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'pikaday'`

Uncaught Error: `[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…84%2FAngularSpring%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)`

**Update:**

I have sorted my script tags like this:

Now I get an error like this:

Uncaught Error: `[$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…84%2FAngularSpring%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)`

Comment: you should include `pikaday.js` after angular files.

Comment: how and where do you bootstrap angular?

Comment: @Maximus I didn't get you. Angular is already boostrapped in myApp

Comment: @Satyadev could you make sure that pikaday.js exist on directory bower_components/handsontable/dist/pikaday?

Comment: @Satyadev, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37362854/2545680)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="bower_components/handsontable/dist/pikaday/pikaday.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'angular-jwt', 'ngStorage', 'angular-storage', 'angularCSS', 'ngHandsontable', 'ngMoment', 'pikaday']);

Comment: Now I get an error: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'zeroclipboard'` after sorting the tags like above

Comment: I have sorted the script tags and now I am getting new error. Please check the updated question once

Answer (score 0):

It seems that pikaday isn't defined as angular module, it's defined as global `Pikaday` object, if you don't use commonJs or AMD loaders:

```
(function (root, factory)
{
    'use strict';

    var moment;
    if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // CommonJS module
        // Load moment.js as an optional dependency
        try { moment = require('moment'); } catch (e) {}
        module.exports = factory(moment);
    } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(function (req)
        {
            // Load moment.js as an optional dependency
            var id = 'moment';
            try { moment = req(id); } catch (e) {}
            return factory(moment);
        });
    } else {
        root.Pikaday = factory(root.moment);
    }
}(this, factory))
```

And I don't think you need to use is as angular module. Try simply removing it from the angular module dependencies. `handsontable` references it inside as global as well, not as angular module.

**Update**

Try loading like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ngHandsontable/dist/ngHandsontable.js"></script>

var myModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngHandsontable'])
```

It gives no error for me

Comment: I removed it from angular module and I still get the same error

Comment: also remove `ngMoment`, it's taken from the window inside `pikaday`, as you can see from the code I listed in my answer

Comment: Shall I also remove `pikaday` from injection? Please check the updated question

Comment: What do you mean from injection? And you should load angular.min.js first. Also why do load both handsontable and handsontable.full ?

Comment: It is mentioned in the documentation so I included both the JS files. I removed `pikaday` from `angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ngHandsontable']);`

Comment: I have loaded angular.min.js first but still the same error: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…84%2FAngularSpring%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)`

Comment: do you have any error when defining like this `angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])`?

Comment: No error. When I remove `ngHandsonTable` I get no error

Comment: try loading like I suggested in my answer

Comment: Just figured out that there is no `ngHandsontable.js` in bowercomponents even though official docs mentioned. So i removed that script tag and loaded according your description and I get error: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A381)`

Comment: You cant remove it from the script tags and load it as dependency for your angular app. it should be in bower components, run bower install again

Comment: No I mean to say `ngHandsontable.js` is not there but instead this file `handsontable.full.js` is there

Comment: you must load nghandsontable using script tag